# Spark: Replace collect()[][] operation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am having code as:

```
new_df=spark.sql("Select col1,col2 from table1 where id=2").collect()[0][0]
```

I have tried toLocalIterator() but getting message that is not subscriptable.
Please suggest a better way to replace collect()[0][0].

Comment: In theory... `.collect()` will give you a list or `Row`s. `.collect()[0]` will give you the first `Row`. What is `[0]` on a `Row` supposed to return?

Comment: @ernest_k my 1st field is a list, so with extra [0] I am trying to get first element of that.

Comment: But you are not reading *that* field from `.collect()[0]`, right?

Comment: @ernest_k No I am not reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC -

Assume this is the resulted DF

```
+----+---+---------------+
|  id|num|       list_col|
+----+---+---------------+
|1001|  5|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|
|1002|  3|      [1, 2, 3]|
+----+---+---------------+
```

In order to get the first value of list_col use one more [] in your existing code

```
print(df.select("list_col").collect()[0][0][0])
will give you 1
```

Likewise, this will give you 2

```
print(df.select("list_col").collect()[0][0][1])
```

**Updating my answer as per new understanding -**
**i.e. To access the first element of a list column from a dataframe**

```
df = df.withColumn("list_element", F.col("list_col").getItem(0))
df.show()
+----+---+---------------+------------+
|  id|num|       list_col|list_element|
+----+---+---------------+------------+
|1001|  5|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|           1|
|1002|  3|      [1, 2, 3]|           1|
+----+---+---------------+------------+
```

Comment: But I need to replace collect() here with other alternative.

Comment: I don't think we have much alternative for collect() in case you want to do in a DF way - read the column in a DF -> do the necessary parsing something like this df = df.withColumn("list_element", F.col("list_col").getItem(0))
df.show()